# Passing date in SOAP Request

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

I am trying to generate SOAP request using SOAP UI. I want to pass in today's date into the xml to get all meetings happening today from the server. Here is my code

Sample Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext" xmlns:urn="urn:ebx-schemas:dataservices_1.0">
   <soapenv:Header>
  <sec:Security>
     <UsernameToken>
        <Username>***</Username>
        <Password>****</Password>
     </UsernameToken>
  </sec:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <urn:select_meeting>        
     <branch>Reference</branch>

     <instance>DFAT_Master_Data</instance>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <predicate></predicate>

<disableRedirectionToLastBroadcast>false</disableRedirectionToLastBroadcast>
  </urn:select_meeting>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is my sample response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ns1:select_meetingResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:ebx-schemas:dataservices_1.0">
     <data>
        <root>
           <meeting>
              <mdmmeetingID>1</mdmmeetingID>
              <subject>qwertyuio</subject>
              <attendeesExternal>Professor</attendeesExternal>
              <meetingRoom>14</meetingRoom>
              <dateTime>2019-11-05T11:12:13.000</dateTime>
              <attachments>cdvdcgdf</attachments>
           </meeting>

           </root>
           </data>
           </ns1:select_meetingResponse>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Ideally I want to pass todays date into the predicate option in request xml.
Can some one help me out?

Answer (score 4):

To get today's date in ISO format you can use

```
${=def now = new Date();now.format("yyyy-MM-dd")}
```

E.g.

```
<predicate>${=def now = new Date();now.format("yyyy-MM-dd")}</predicate>
```

becomes

```
<predicate>2019-05-09</predicate>
```

Change the string argument to `format` to suit your needs.